# Trying to align my image and list at center

Tags: html, css

Im trying t align my image and my list at center but its not working with `margin:0 auto;`.

And also I want to have my image at left and my list at right, but the opposite is happening.

Someone see what Im doing wrong?

My example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3yqnj7s6/2/

Html:

```
<div class="col_12">

    <div class="center">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/2/2f/Beyonc%C3%A9_-_Dangerously_in_Love.jpg" width="430" height="430" />
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Test:</strong> 24 july 2003</li>
            <li><strong>Test:</strong> 2002 - 2003;
                <span>Patchwerk Studios</span>
                <span>(Atlanta, Georgia)</span>
                <span>SugarHill Studios</span>
                <span>(Houston, Texas)</span>
                <span>South Beach Studios</span>
                <span>(Miami)</span>
                <span>Baseline Studios</span>
                <span>SoHo Studios</span>
                <span>Sony Music Studios</span>
                <span>COE.BE.3 Studios</span>
                <span>(Stone Mountain, Georgia)</span></li>
            <li><strong>Test:</strong> R&B, Soul</li>
            <li><strong>Test:</strong> Columbia</li>
            <li><strong>Singles:</strong> Crazy in love, Baby boy, Me, myself and I, Naughty Girl</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col_12
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin:0 auto;
padding:15px;
background:#ccc;
}


.col_12 .center{
    margin:0 auto;

    text-align:center;
    background:red;

}

.col_12 p
{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}

.col_12 ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}

.col_12 ul li{
    text-align:left;
}

.col_12 ul li span{
    display:block;
    margin-left:82px;

}
```

Comment: It looks ok in the fiddle.

Comment: [`float` the image to `left` and the unordered list to `right`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3yqnj7s6/5/).

Comment: Thanks Mary Melody, it seems that is working fine! But can you explain me how your solution worked? Im not understanding. And also can you give the answer so I can accept it? Thanks one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution to get the `img` on the left and the `ul` on the right... Note that the last two CSS entries both have a `max-width` so as to prevent one of the items from dropping off if the other item is too big (which you can remove from the code if you want to):

```
.col_12 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.col_12 .center {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.col_12 p {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.col_12 ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
.col_12 ul li {
    text-align: left;
}
.col_12 ul li span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 82px;
}
/*
  Find the img tag(s) after the div(s) whose classes are "center":
*/
.center img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 75%;
}
/*
  Find the ul tag(s) after the div(s) whose classes are "center":
*/
.center ul {
    float: right;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```